# Is $\alpha$ a norm in the extension $K(\sqrt[n]{\alpha})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this.  $K$ is a field of characteristic zero containing all $n$th roots of unity, and $\alpha \in K$.  Let $L = K(\sqrt[n]{\alpha})$, $\mu$ the minimal polynomial of $\beta = \sqrt[n]{\alpha}$ over $K$.  Then $\mu$ divides $X^n - \alpha = \prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(X - \zeta^i \beta)$, so $N_{L/K}(\beta) = \prod\limits_k \zeta^k \beta$ for some subcollection $k$ of $0, 1, ... , n-1$.  Is $\alpha$ itself a norm from $L$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $K=\mathbb{R}$ and $n=-2$ (certainly, $\mathbb{R}$ does have all $2$nd roots of unity). Let $\alpha=-1$, so that $\beta=i$ (or just as well, $\beta=-i$) and $L=\mathbb{C}$.

Then we have $N_{L/K}(\beta)=(i)(-i)=1$, and in fact $N_{L/K}(z)=|z|^2\geq 0$ for all $z\in L$, so that $\alpha$ is not a norm from $L$.

Comment: Though, still, one might imagine that the question had an error-up-to-sign in it...